# WCF - library naming convention

Tags: wcf

I got a few WCFs that are running on an intranet on IIS 7.

I wonder how I would keep them tidy, an option would be to use subdomains, e.g.

```
mailbox.wcf.myserver.com
location.wcf.myserver.com
```

Or maybe a specific server for each wcf,

```
mailboxlibrary.myserver.com
locationlibrary.myserver2.com
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are asking about how to name a web resource. This has nothing to do with WCF or any other framework that might be hosting your web resource.

This is very debatable, but in my opinion, the technology used to develop a web resource should not be mentioned in the dns name of that resource.

I would rather name the web resource based on what it truly represent. (mailboxservice.xxx.com and locationservice.xxx.com sound like "good" names)

you are also making the decision of getting an additional server based on the name of the service? This is wrong. (seems like you have servers to waste. I'll get one of them :))

Decide where you host your services based on the load requirements, and network constraints.

If you want to use a single host, but want the host name to look fancy for each service, you'll need a DNS server (if your company doesn't already have one). Just setup the right name entries and point them to the same server.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/168322